# Effectiveness of feces as a fertilzer

Tags: botany

How effective is feces such as cows, chicken or horses for fertilizing the earth of a garden in order to grow crops.

Comment: What crops are we exactly talking about and what feces are we exactly talking about? It mostly depends on those plants' chemical needs and the chemicals in the feces of those animals (and the chemicals present in the soil where that plant is located, and even the current growth stage of the plant).

Comment: I am thinking about staple food crops such as carrots, potatoes, cucumbers or yams.

Comment: How do you measure effectiveness?  Consider that people have been doing it for probably thousands of years, and still do so today.  Or walk around a cow pasture and notice how the grass grows far more lushly around each cowflop.  Or read throught the 30K or so hits on Google Scholar: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C29&q=effectiveness+of+manure+as+garden+fertilizer&btnG=

Comment: It depends largely on the crop there are many papers about it.  You will have an easier time searching for manure instead of feces. https://tropicalsoybean.com/sites/default/files/Comparative%20effectiveness%20of%20cattle%20manure,%20poultry%20manure_Ghosh,%202004.pdf and https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,31&q=effectiveness+of+manure+as+fertilizer

Comment: Thank you, I will read into this further.

Comment: Horse manure allows the propagation of the plants etc that horses eat as they do not process the seeds.